# CoreData shared entity properties

Tags: swift, core-data, properties

I'm new to Swift/CoreData and SQl databases. I have a CoreDatabase with over 7000 items. I want to create an entity (or any other way) to store how often a certain entry in the DB has been used. I need this in order to create a weighted sorting algorithm that suggests certain entries.

The catch is that I do not want to store this on the entries themselves, they need to remain generic in order for me to be able to update them every now and again via my own Node server. So all users have the same DB. Whenever the user picks one of the items it's counter increments by one. Whenever I query an item the frequency should come with it so I can perform a sorting algorithm on it.

I've been reading up on articles, it seems like this can be done, but none so far have been really useful. I've also looked a SQLite articles on this but haven't found what I was looking for.

I'm thinking something along these lines:

```
FrequencyList {                  Item_1 {          ...7000 items....
   item_1_freq : 0,  ------------>   frequency :  0,
   item_2_freq : 12,                 name: "lala"
   item_3_freq : 3                   ...
   ...                             };
   ...
   7000?!?!
};
```

Or would a separate 'meta' entity in a one-to-one relationship with it's respective Item be a good solution?

How can I tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Core Data it would probably be better like this:

[image]

Put the selection in an entity with a `count` property, and have a relationship between the selection and the item. The `Selection` --> `Item` relationship could be to-one or to-many depending on your needs; I have it as to-many here but that might not be best in your case.

If you want to get the number of selections for an `Item`, use the value of `selection.count`. Update `selection.count` when a selection occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've got a few more questions if you, or anyone has the time.. If I were to update the database I would somehow need to preserve the relationship even though it will be a new instance of the Item. Is that possible in CoreData?. Also; are shared entity properties even possible, or something I made up :P?

Comment: Your question about updating needs more detail before I can tell what the answer might be-- maybe try a new question. "Shared" entity properties only exist if one entity inherits from another one, in which case the child entity inherits properties from the parent.